# Retornar dados via Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Bom dia a todos... Preciso de uma ajuda... Preciso retornar valores de sucesso ou erro via ajax. Mas não está retornando nada. Segue os codigos:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="cep" name="ceps" placeholder="_____-___">
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning botao" id="buscar">Calcular</button>
<div id="resultad"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#buscar').click(function(){
        $.ajax({                
            type:'POST',
            url:'/inc-busca-cep.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data:{
                cep: $('cep').val()
            },              
            success: function(data){
                if (data){
                     $('#resultad').html('<span class="text-danger">Não entregamos neste cep</span>');
               } else {
                     $('#resultad').html('<span class="text-danger">Entregamos neste cep. Frete Grátis!</span>');
               }
            },

        });

        return false;
    });
```

**PHP**

```
$pdo = db_connect();
$cep = isset($_POST['cep']) ? $_POST['cep'] : null;
function limpa($valor){ $valor = trim($valor); $valor = str_replace("-", "", $valor); return $valor;}

$cepLimpo = limpa($cep);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ceps WHERE :a BETWEEN cep_de AND cep_ate");                                    
$stmt->bindParam(':a', $cepLimpo);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if($result):
  echo "ok";
else:
  echo "erro";
endif;
```

Comment: Porque deve estar dando erro de sintaxe no JS e você não viu. Reveja a sua condição dentro da *callback* `success`; existe um `if` que não possui, de fato, uma condição.

Comment: Entendi, mas não sei como fazer :( estou aprendendo ajax ainda.... Sei somente usar o if no php

Comment: Isso é sintaxe do JavaScript, não tem relação com o AJAX e a sintaxe é a mesma do PHP. Se não sabe isso ainda, recomendo que estude ao menos o básico do JavaScript antes de tentar fazer algo mais avançado: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss agora entendi o que você quis dizer... fazer a mesma coisa que fiz no if no PHP...

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss fiz o ajuste no IF do JS, mas mesmo assim nao me retorna nada...

Answer (score 1):

Modifique sua função de success, antes das condicionais coloque isto:

```
    console.warn('retorno:', data);
```

Então abra o console do navegador na guia "console" e poste um print do resultado aqui...

Comment: Consegui fazer retornar o ok ou erro... mas como eu faço um if no Ajax?
success: function(data) {
    if ("ok"){
    $('#resultad').html('<span class="text-danger">Não entregamos neste cep</span>');
    } else {
    $('#resultad').html('<span class="text-danger">Entregamos neste cep. Frete Grátis!</span>'); 
    }
          console.log('Success!', data);
    },
   error: function(e) {    
    console.log('Error!', e);
    }

Comment: Veja, repare que você recebe o valor devido no atributo "data", sendo assim você tem que fazer a condicional verificando o valor deste atributo!

Comment: Se você fizer isso:

        if (data) { // faz algo }

A condicional vai verificar de forma booleana, ou seja, se o dado retornado for 0, undefined, null, false ou string vazia("") o resultado será FALSE e o IF não será executado passando para o ELSE.

Comment: Você pode deixar o código do ajax da maneira que estava la no inicio, porém terá que responder um valor booleano no ECHO do servidor...

Exemplo: echo 1(se for tudo certo) e echo 0(se tiver erro).

Porém como o seu servidor retorna como resposta as strings "ok" e "erro", então você deve fazer a condicional da seguinte forma:

if (data === "ok") { // sucesso }
else { // fracasso(se for qualquer coisa diferente de "ok") }

Comment: mto obg funcionou certinho... e obg a todos pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente a requisição ajax não está errada. Deve haver algum erro em seu script php fiz um simulação aqui com um codigo similar e funcionou. Verifique se adicionou o jquery e o script javascript a sua pagina html corretamente ao final do arquivo:

Abaixo um exemplo que funcionou

HTML:

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="cep" name="ceps" placeholder="_____-___">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning botao" id="buscar">Calcular</button>
    <div id="resultad"></div>

   <!-- Adiciona JQUERY e script js para requisição ajax -->
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/main2.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
        $('#buscar').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/post2.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                cep: $('cep').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    $('#resultad').html('<span class="text-danger">Não entregamos neste cep</span>');
                } else {
                    $('#resultad').html('<span class="text-danger">Entregamos neste cep. Frete Grátis!</span>');
                }
            },


        });

        return false;
    });
```

PHP (Simplifiquei apresentado apenas um echo para simular o seu codigo)

```
    <?php 

echo "ok";
```

Comment: Em caso de duvida debugue o seu script com console.log(data)

Comment: Onde coloco esse console.log(data)